# "algebraic" literature

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

could anyone recommend me an introduction into

(i) group theory,

(ii) algebraic number theory?

(Consider that as two different questions.) Why do you think, that a book you suggest, is good? Thank you for any suggestions/discussion/etc.

Comment: What level are you at?  Intro, undergrad, graduate, other?

Comment: Well, I've passed just first two semesters (of bachelor study) at university, so level intro, I would say.

Comment: There's a cool book called Algebra Zero that I think would be appropriate.  I found a pdf online if you google for it.

Comment: You mean this one? https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Chapter-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847813

Comment: Yes that's the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have studied group theory out of Artin's *Algebra*, a classic text that is considered 'standard' by many. However, Dummit and Foote is becoming increasingly popular, and looking through the first sections I can see the first six chapters devoted entirely to group theory, which may be what you need.

A good soft introduction to Algebraic Number Theory is Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*.  This is not really a text solely devoted to algebraic number theory, as it reviews elementary number theory but in the context of ring theory and principal ideal domains(initially).

In reality, the choice of what book/resource/etc. you study from is less important than *solving problems*, so I would just say pick something and start doing it.

Comment: Those are probably all way too advanced for a sophomore undergraduate.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It differs from person to person.  The only way to find out if it's too hard is to start working through.

Comment: Well of course he might be a prodigy, but we all know Artin is written to be a graduate text, not a first text except maybe at Princeton.